# Bad request for http request google drive offline access

Tags: .net, httprequest, access-token, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get offline access with the refreshtoken. With a httprequest I have to get a new accessToken with the saved refreshToken.

But I keep getting a Bad Request 400 with no further explanation what's wrong. Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code or post a code that does work??

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");

authenticator.ApplyAuthenticationToRequest(request);

request.Method = "POST";

String para = "code='"+refreshtoken+"'&client_id='" + ClientCredentials.CLIENT_ID + "'&client_secret='" + ClientCredentials.CLIENT_SECRET + "'&grant_type='refresh_token'";

System.IO.Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

System.IO.StreamWriter streamwriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(requestStream);

streamwriter.Write(para);
streamwriter.Close();

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
String result = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Function httpReq(uri As String, para As String, host As String, method As String) As String
    Dim responseData As String = ""
    Dim postData As String = para
    Dim encoding As New ASCIIEncoding()
    Dim byte1() As Byte = encoding.GetBytes(postData)

    Dim httpWebRequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(uri)
    httpWebRequest.Method = method
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    httpWebRequest.ContentLength = byte1.Length

    Dim newStream As IO.Stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
    newStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length)
    newStream.Close()

    Dim httpWebResponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse()
    If httpWebResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK Then
        Dim responseReader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
        responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd()
    End If
    httpWebResponse.Close()
    Return responseData
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the client [library for .NET](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/), and if you could paste the complete request and response, that might help.